# liquibase - how to rollback an insert change set that is using sequence to populate id field

Tags: oracle, liquibase

I am trying to use liquibase to perform db changes for each deployed version (I'm using oracle db).

When I insert new data to a table, I'm using sequence to populate the ID field. But it is also important to me to have the abilty to rollback this insert - meaning delete the newly created row with the id create from the next value of the sequnece.

My question is how to write a rollback to the `changeSet` that will delete the new row using the created id from the sequence. (I can't use the sequence itself because its value can change many times before perfroming the rollback)

For example:

```json
{
    "changeSet": {
        "id": 1,
        "author": "somebody",
        "changes": [
            {
               "insert": {
                   "tableName": "EMPLOYEES".
                   "columns": [
                      {
                         "column": {
                             "name": "id",
                             "valueSequenceNext": "EMPLOYEES_SEQ"
                         }
                      },
                      {
                         "column": {
                             "name": "name",
                             "value": "john dou"
                         }
                      }
                   ]
               }
            }
        ],
        "rollback": "here rollback the insert using the sequence"
    }
}
```

Comment: The kind of rollback you are describing does not appear to be an option with Liquibase, based on the documentation here: https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/liquibase-community/using-rollback.html. Rollback commands must be tag-based, time-based, or count-based. Liquibase Pro offers a  couple of other options, but none of them allow you to specify properties of the change set (other than tags) as parameters for the rollback.

Comment: I can create a tag before this specific change set, or rollback by count of change sets - that’s not the problem. The problem is that if I want to perform rollback for an insert change set, I need to define specific custom rollback clause, and currently I don’t know how to use the new id created from the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

If it's possible that you created many new inserts using that sequence,  before performing rollback, then it's not possible to rollback it automatically.

Quick, not ideal workaround:

- what about creating additional TEMP_TABLE table to store this created_id?
- columns: CREATED_ID, CHANGESET_ID, ORDINAL_NUMBER
- write a rollback to DELETE row from TEMP_TABLE where ORDINAL_NUMBER is MAX(ORDINAL_NUMBER)?

Can't see any other options, Liquibase itself doesn't store any info about inserted records.

Comment: Yeah I don’t want to create a new table for this, but it’s not a bad idea at all. It is a little bit disappointing that liquibase doesn’t support this. Anyway my final solution was not to rollback change sets that perform insert (using labels). It works for me because the data I use liquibase to insert does not effect the application if it is not deleted.